# What is the type of ViewerEvent in Stimulsoft?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stimulsoft

I use `AccessControlFilter` to check the `AccessPerson`. I want to exclude `ViewerEvent` in StimulSoft and all have this access. However, I do not know what that type is.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve] of your progress so far.

Answer (score 0):

ViewerEvent is of type `IActionResult`. **ViewerEvent** and **GetReport** are in Actions group. `IActionResult` is an interface.

https://www.stimulsoft.com/en/samples/mvc/using-the-viewer-and-designer-in-one-project